# stretch the boxes to have an organized menu with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a menu and I want to stretch the boxes in this menu to have an organized one

I tried like this,this is my code:

```
 <div class="col-sm-1">
                <ul class="nav-gproS">
                    <li>
                <a style="margin-top: 10px" class="btn btn-action pull-right" 
                        href="" ng-click="go1()">F.Suiveuse</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="active">
                <a style="margin-top: 10px" class="btn btn-action pull-right"
                        href="" ng-click="go2()">Suivi/Poste</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                <a style="margin-top: 10px" class="btn btn-action pull-right" 
                        href="" ng-click="go3()">Personnel</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                <a style="margin-top: 10px" class="btn btn-action pull-right" 
                        href="" ng-click="go4()">Avct OF</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

and this is the CSS code:

```
 .nav-gproS {
        list-style-type: none;
    }
    .btn-action {
        background: #1f8597;
        color: #fff;
        border-radius: 0px;
        font-weight: 600;
    }
    .btn {
        font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Segoe UI', 'Droid Sans', Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
        border-width: 0px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.07);
        box-shadow: inset 0 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.07);
    }
    .pull-right {
        float: right !important;
    }
```

what I get is a non organized menu,so how can modify my CSS
thanks for help

Comment: `display: block; width: 120px; /*or what suits best*/`

Comment: add `btn-block` class to your `<a>`s

Comment: can you explain more Sir I am new in CSS world :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm suggesting adding to your existing `<a>` tags class `.btn-block`. Also remove `.pull-right` and set `text-align: right` to your `.btn-action` declaration or add class `.text-right`.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style>
  .nav-gproS {
    list-style-type: none;
  }
  .btn-action {
    background: #1f8597;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 0px;
    text-align: right;
    /* text right added here*/
    font-weight: 600;
  }
  .btn {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Segoe UI', 'Droid Sans', Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
    border-width: 0px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
  }
  .pull-right {
    float: right !important;
  }
</style>
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <ul class="nav-gproS">
    <li>
      <a style="margin-top: 10px" class="btn btn-action btn-block" href="" ng-click="go1()">F.Suiveuse</a>
    </li>
    <li class="active">
      <a style="margin-top: 10px" class="btn btn-action  btn-block" href="" ng-click="go2()">Suivi/Poste</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a style="margin-top: 10px" class="btn btn-action  btn-block" href="" ng-click="go3()">Personnel</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a style="margin-top: 10px" class="btn btn-action  btn-block" href="" ng-click="go4()">Avct OF</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
.nav-gproS {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.nav-gproS a {              /*Set a width on your links, so they get the same width*/
  width: 150px;
  text-align: right;
}

.btn-action {
    background: #1f8597;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 0px;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.btn {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Segoe UI', 'Droid Sans', Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
    border-width: 0px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.07);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.07);
}

.pull-right {
    float: right !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using Bootstrap I have another suggestion.  Remove the list entirely and add `.btn-block` to your anchors since Bootstrap can handle anchors as full-width, block-style buttons already.

[Check This Out](http://www.bootply.com/yGJAJhXReO)

```
<div class="col-sm-1">
            <a style="margin-top: 10px" class="btn btn-block btn-action" href="" ng-click="go1()">F.Suiveuse</a>
            <a style="margin-top: 10px" class="btn btn-block btn-action" href="" ng-click="go2()">Suivi/Poste</a>
            <a style="margin-top: 10px" class="btn btn-block btn-action" href="" ng-click="go3()">Personnel</a>
            <a style="margin-top: 10px" class="btn btn-block btn-action" href="" ng-click="go4()">Avct OF</a>
</div>
```

```
.btn-action {
    background: #1f8597;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 0px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.btn {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Segoe UI', 'Droid Sans', Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
    border-width: 0px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.07);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.07);
}
```